# Building capybara-webkit on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, capybara-webkit

I'm trying to use capybara-webkit on Windows 7 and am having problems.  I'm trying to follow the instructions [here](https://github.com/thoughtbot/capybara-webkit/wiki/Installing-Qt-and-compiling-capybara-webkit) but am having problems.  Specifically I'm having issues building from source.  The following is a small extract of the very large output from building.

This first output is from where the error is happening.

```
g++ -c -pipe -g -frtti -fexceptions -mthreads -Wall -Wextra -DUNICODE -DQT_LARGEFILE_SUPPORT -DQT_DLL -DQT_WEBKIT_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_NETWORK_LIB -D QT_CORE_LIB -DQT_HAVE_MMX -DQT_HAVE_3DNOW -DQT_HAVE_SSE -DQT_HAVE_MMXEXT -DQT_HAVE_SSE2 -DQT_THREAD_SUPPORT -I'c:/Qt/4.8.4/include/QtCore' -I'c:/Qt/4.8.4/include/QtNetwork' -I'c:/Qt/4.8.4/include/QtGui' -I'c:/Qt/4.8.4/include/QtWebKit' -I'c:/Qt/4.8.4/include' -I'c:/Qt/4.8.4/include/ActiveQt' -I'debug' -I'c:/Qt/4.8.4/mkspecs/win32-g++' -o debug/qrc_webkit_server.o debug/qrc_webkit_server.cpp
g++ -Wl,-subsystem,console -mthreads -o debug/webkit_server.exe object_script.webkit_server.Debug  -L'c:/Qt/4.8.4/lib' -lQtWebKitd4 -lQtGuid4 -lQtNetworkd4 -lQtCored4
./debug/Version.o: In function `ZN7Version5startEv':
c:\MyRailsProject\capybara-webkit\src/Version.cpp:11: undefined reference to `_imp___Z14qWebKitVersionv'
./debug/Version.o: In function `ZN7QStringpLERKS_':
c:/Qt/4.8.4/include/QtCore/../../src/corelib/tools/qstring.h:274: undefined reference to `_imp___ZN7QString6appendERKS_'
./debug/Version.o: In function `QString':
c:/Qt/4.8.4/include/QtCore/../../src/corelib/tools/qstring.h:419: undefined reference to `_imp___ZN7QString16fromAscii_helperEPKci'
```

This is from the very end of the very long output chain

```
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [debug/webkit_server.exe] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/c/MyRailsProject/capybara-webkit/src'
make[1]: *** [debug] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/c/MyRailsProject/capybara-webkit/src'
make: *** [sub-src-webkit_server-pro-make_default-ordered] Error 2
Command 'make' failed
```

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong and how to correctly compile capybara-webkit?

Answer (score 2):

I actually solved this by getting the correct version of QT.  I had originally downloaded the Visual Studios 2008 version, but after changing to the MingGW version everything works as expected.